# AJAX download file from Express results in "this site attempted to download multiple files" (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, svelte

Why is this so convoluted? I want to download a file and I get this error:

```
this site attempted to download multiple files
```

**How can I prevent this error and actually download the file?**

If I disable the block, it works fine... But It's really bad UX to have the client do this.

what is it that I am triggering here, as I only download a single file?

I am using the svelte framework, if it changes anything.

**client**

```js
async function downloadFile(fieldId, fileName) {
        let response = await fetchGetFile(`/api/files/${fieldId}`);
        let blob = await response.blob();
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.style.display = "none";
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;

        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        a.remove();
    }
```

**server**

```js
router.get("/api/files/:fileId", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let { fileId } = req.params;

        let query = `
            select *
            from file
            where id = ?
        `;

        let rows = await req.asyncQuery(query, [fileId]);

        let data = rows[0];

        let file = path.join(__dirname, `/../uploads/${data.fileName}`);

        res.download(file);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    } finally {
        req.connection.release();
    }
});
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your entire client-side code can be replaced with `window.open(\`/api/files/${fieldId}\`)`. Try that first.

Comment: API routes are authorized i.e. a token must be provided. This way it can't work. However, I can use `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` as the `window.open()` URL, but this doesn't download the file, as it opens it in the browser.

Comment: The error is caused by a security measure in Chrome; I don't see how you can prevent this unless you change your way of authorizing downloads to cookies, which should make my suggestion work.

Comment: `unless you change your way of authorizing downloads to cookies`
Can you please elaborate this a bit? I didn't quite get it.

Comment: Your server uses a token for authorization, correct? Which means if you use a [session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) instead, the session cookie will be included in all requests, including opening a window/tab with one of your URLs. That way you can use `window.open` and still authorize the user.

Comment: I see. That would go against the RESTful convention no?

Comment: Yes, but unless you advise your users not to use Chrome (or this is a bug and they fix it) I don't see another way. And you can always append the token to the URL (not sure if that's a good idea though, security-wise)